# docker swarm - first docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker-compose, swarm

I'm trying to run my first container on docker swarm and have following issue:
on swarm node it is looping - starting 1,2,3 seconds and initialising like in a loop,

I don't know if because of my docker-compose this fails - maybe I created wrong yml file.

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
  app1:
    image: debian:latest
    #    command: sh -c 'apt update'
    #command: sh -c 'apt install ssh -y'
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
        resources:
          limits:
            cpus: '2'
            memory: 2G
          reservations:
            cpus: '2'
            memory: 2G

networks:
  net1:
    driver: overlay
```

Answer (score 0):

The plain debian image is just going to go to an interactive session, which counts as an exit when nothing is attached.

You need to do something like this to keep a plain linux os image alive as a service:

```yaml
services:
  my-service:
    image: debian
    command: tail -f /dev/null
```